# BigIntger Giving error with decimal containing input

Tags: c#

I've written a code for Large Integer input that might contain decimal vale . I've opted the bigInt approach for this but this is not accepting input with decimal value

```
{
  Console.WriteLine("Enter Your first number :");
  BigInteger bigInt1 = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Second number :");
  BigInteger bigInt2 = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  BigInteger sum = bigInt1 + bigInt2;
  Console.WriteLine("Result after adding two Bumbers is :" + "\t" + sum);
}
```

Comment: An integer is, by definition, a 'whole' number. It's not clear how you expect this to work. If you actually want a number with decimals, use `double` or `decimal` instead.

Comment: An example of input that fails? How does it fail (wrong result, exception)?

Answer (score -2):

You should use `Convert.ToInt64` like so, first convert the string from the `Console.ReadLine()` and then parse it to `decimal`.

```
{
  Console.WriteLine("Enter Your first number :");
  var input = Console.ReadLine();
  var num = Decimal.Parse(input);
  BigInteger bigInt1 = Convert.ToInt64(num);
}
```

Comment: Why would you convert to a `long` first? You could just cast the `decimal` to `BigInteger`. But why use `BigInteger` to deal with decimal numbers?

Comment: @CharlesMager I am not sure i understand your question, this is what the author of this post asks for?

Comment: @AliyaZafar and integer doesn't have decimals, by definition. There is no such thing as a 'decimal value integer'.

Comment: @AliyaZafar please explain what do do mean and give example for an input you are trying to set.

Comment: i am giving input like num1=45456547567.67787899 and num 2 = 4353456346546546546 (INPut that can't b handled by just int n might contain decimal point as well)

Comment: @AliyaZafar and those numbers are *not integers*, so you can't parse them as integers. Use `double` or `decimal` instead.

Comment: @AliyaZafar I tested your inputs against my code and the conversion is correct, off course i will lose the decimal point when converting something into an int.

Comment: But what if i want the answer in decimal ... I guess for that I have to use Convert.ToDecimal(); instead of toint

Comment: @AliyaZafar no, as `num` in this case is already `decimal`. `Convert.ToDecimal(num)` would be redundant.

Comment: it is working fine with decimal values but when i enter just numbers e.g num1 =8888888888888888888 it throw exception :(

Comment: @AliyaZafar first of all i don't get an exception with this number running my code, second of all you have to give us more details about the exception you are getting.

Comment: @Shlomi Haver  it throws an exception of System.OverflowException When i enter first number = 8888888888888888888888888

Comment: @AliyaZafar off course is throws this error because you entered a number larger then what `Int64` could get which is: 9223372036854775807